# Residual autocorrelation in VAR with non stationary data

Tags: autocorrelation, vector-autoregression, stationarity

I am running VAR model with non-stationary time series. I am going to have a look only at impulse response functions, so I've read that I can use VAR for non-stationary time series. My model includes 4 variables. According to all ICs (AIC, HQ, SC), the lag order must be 2. But in VAR(2) model there is an autocorrelation in residuals of one variable. Is it a big problem? Can I continue my analysis with this problem?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You have to be careful when putting non-stationary processes into VAR. If the processes are not cointegrated, the estimation procedure may result in *spurious regression*. That is when the true coefficient is 0 but we get false significance with probability higher than the significance level.

In general, you have to explain all the serial correlation in residuals if statistical inference is the goal.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I run two VARs. In the first one the variables are cointegrated. Is the autocorrelation ok in this case? In the second one some of the variables are cointegrated. What should I do in this case? Can the reason of autocorrelation be also an ommited variable?

Comment: Only if your goal is building a black-boxy model for relatively accurate forecasting out of sample... However, if your goal is to understand the mechanism behind the interplay of X and Y, capturing the codependence in residuals is important.

Comment: Actually I am going to proceed my analysis with running SVAR model with sign restrictions and then look at the impulse response functions. I guess in this case the autocorrelation is really a big problem. How can I solve it? Do I need to turn to VECM or VAR with stationary data?